# Linear programming exercise with constraints in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-programming

I'm looking for a library or any other solution for the problem like below.

I have a matrix that I need to fill, possibly randomly, with a fixed number of 1s. Additionally each row and each column have a max value defined that cannot be exceeded (so for example there can be max five 1s in row A and six 1s in column A).

Is there an easy, automatic way to do it in R? I'd need a solution for bigger matrices, for example 50x50.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15sUE.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: There are many LP/MIP solvers available under R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with `lpSolveAPI`:

```
fill_matrix <- function(nrow, ncol, n, maxcol, maxrow) {
    lprec <- make.lp(ncol=nrow*ncol, nrow=nrow+ncol+1)
    set.objfn(lprec, rep(0, nrow*ncol))
    set.type(lprec, 1:(nrow*ncol), "binary")
    for (i in 1:nrow) set.row(lprec, row=i, xt=rep(1,ncol), indices=seq(i, by=nrow, length.out=ncol))
    set.constr.type(lprec, rep("<=", nrow), constraints = 1:nrow)
    set.rhs(lprec, rep(maxrow, nrow), constraints=1:nrow)
    for (i in 1:ncol) set.row(lprec, row=nrow+i, xt=rep(1,nrow), indices=((i-1)*nrow)+1:nrow)
    set.constr.type(lprec, rep("<=", ncol), constraints=nrow+1:ncol)
    set.rhs(lprec, rep(maxcol, ncol), constraints=nrow+1:ncol)
    set.row(lprec, row=nrow+ncol+1, xt=rep(1,nrow*ncol))
    set.constr.type(lprec, "=", nrow+ncol+1)
    set.rhs(lprec, n, nrow+ncol+1)
    status <- solve(lprec)
    if(status!=0) stop("could not solve")
    matrix(get.variables(lprec), ncol=ncol, nrow=nrow)
}
```

Now `fill_matrix(6,5,10,2,2)` produces one 6x5-matrix with exactly 10 ones and at most 2 ones per row/column.

Comment: Thank you vm @Karsten W.